checking on whether a streamreader is open gives a warning in VB.net
This scheme
        Try
        SR= New StreamReader(...)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, vbOK, "Error opening File")
        GoTo wrapup
    End Try  
... {do things}
    wrapup:
        SR.Dispose()
        If SR IsNot Nothing Then SR.Close()
        If SR.BaseStream IsNot Nothing Then SR.Close()

Any of the three ways of closing the Streamreader-SR gives a warning that SR is used before assignment. Is there a proper way to close something you're not sure is open?

The data flow analysis used to generate warnings about use before assignment is somewhat limited in capability, so it sometimes gives spurious warnings (where you can clearly see that it really is initialized on all code paths).  It also treats all assignments equally, so you can quiet it by assigning Nothing which is really no safer than assigning nothing at all, though I suppose the act indicates you've at least looked at it.

You should be using Finally instead of the GoTo wrapup arrangement.

StreamReader implements IDisposable. As such, the cleanest way is to use the Using statement, which will ensure proper closing and disposal when the object goes out of scope.
    Using SR As New StreamReader(...)

        ... {do things}

    End Using

In addition, I recommend you cease using "VB6-compaitble" code, such as MsgBox, and move to current VB.NET constructs such as MessageBox.
I'll hold my tongue on GoTo :-)

Thank you. 1. Is there an explanation for why checking on whether something is null is considering using it?  2. What if the attempt to open and close are not withing the same procedure? for example, a log-file using a STREAMWRITER for various methods to write to and then closing it on mainform.close

@Ernesto in your second case, since it's a class- or module-level variable, it shouldn't produce this warning.  I would recommend to call Dispose manually in that case, ideally within an IDisposable implementation on the host.

@Ernesto 1. You were calling SR.Dispose() before you checked for null (Nothing). 2. That's not a good design. You shouldn't leave the StreamWriter opened. If you need to write to a log file, instantiate the writer, write to the file, and dispose of the writer.

Thanks HardCode. The three statements were used as alternatives, not together. Any of them left in place gives the warning.  Also thanks Craig, it is indeed true the class/module level stream does not give the warning but could give runtime error if indeed it is null which is the purpose of the checking with isNot Nothing. I have switched to Using/End Using, but for a module level stream it seems based on the answers given, it is not a good idea and the stream needs to be open and closed everywhere which seem not very efficient, but that may be the only way.

@Ernesto just write one Public Sub(logMessage As String) which handles writing to the log file, and call that Sub whenever you need to write to the log. Or, don't reinvent the wheel and use Log4net: https://stackify.com/log4net-guide-dotnet-logging/?_sm_vck=PB6LpPM5MmR6Ps4S6VPMD57jjjJnSj84V0SQ0qVlZRmpPksqp2SF
